# Get recipient's email address from a json file in MUTT

Tags: email, ubuntu, mutt, msmtp

So I am using MUTT on my Ubuntu server where I want to email a particular file to the user once he enters his email address in a webpage (hosted on the server).
I am storing his response as a .json file in the server but now I want to send email to the email address provided by him.
As far as i know, MUTT has a command to send the email to a recipient 
`mutt -s "Mail Subject" username@domain.com -a attachment.zip < mail_body.txt`
What I want is, to get the `username@domain` from a file rather than hardcoding it. 
Any leads on how to do this will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had to create an executable script for this job. 
I stored the email to a variable by using `EMAIL=cat email.txt` and then used this EMAIL variable as the recipient.